# CMake: generate sources during CMake script execution

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to migrate my Visual Studio solution to CMake.

I have two projects - generator (generator.exe generates C++ sources from text files) and myProj (includes some text files that have to be processed by generator.exe).
What I want is:

1. build generator project
2. use generator.exe from step1 to generate C++ source files from text files in project myProj
3. put those generated source files in resulting VS project for myProj

So, how to do this?

**EDIT**
what I've tried so far:

```
###################################################################
# in root/generator/CMakeLists.txt:
set(SRC_LIST .... )
set(HDR_LIST .... )
add_executable(generator ${SRC_LIST} ${HDR_LIST})    

###################################################################
# in root/my_proj/CMakeLists.txt:

add_subdirectory(../generator/  ../generator/cmake_out)
add_subdirectory(src)

###################################################################
# in root/my_proj/src/CMakeLists.txt:    

ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(
   OUTPUT ../include/SomeSource.h SomeSource.cpp
   COMMAND generator ../definitions/SomeDefs1.txt
   DEPENDS generator ../definitions/SomeDefs1.txt
   )

set(SRC_LIST SomeSource.cpp .... )
set(HDR_LIST SomeSource.h .... )

add_library(myProj STATIC ${SRC_LIST} ${HDR_LIST} )

###################################################################
###################################################################
```

CMake's output:

```
.....
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler using: Visual Studio 12 2013
-- Check for working CXX compiler using: Visual Studio 12 2013 -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Configuring done
CMake Error at src/CMakeLists.txt:145 (add_library):
  Cannot find source file:

    ../include/SomeSource.h

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp
  .hxx .in .txx
```

Answer (score 2):

Start with CMake's [`add_custom_command()`](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_custom_command.html) and take it from there:

```
add_executable( generator ${generator_SOURCES} )
add_custom_command( OUTPUT source1.cpp source2.cpp
    COMMAND generator args1 args2
    COMMENT "Generating sources..." )
```

Whether or not to integrate myProj into your other project, or keep it external is up to your individual needs, and influences how the final setup would look like.

---

The CMake code you are showing is not the one you are executing. Your `add_library()` lists `SomeSource.h`, but CMake complains about `../include/SomeSource.h`. The directory names also do not work out. This makes it hard to say what exactly is wrong.

My generic suggestion when familiarizing yourself with a new tool: Do **not** immediately try to make it dance *in the context you eventually want it to work in* (myProj, in this case). Instead, set up a simple test environment (with directories X and Y, source files foo.cpp and bar.cpp, you get the idea), and test the *concepts* (like, having `echo` create a file instead of `generator`, so you do not need to build `generator` first -- that's the *next* step).

That way, if any problems pop up, you can ask for help *in the abstract*, and you can provide *complete* example code for others to figure out without having to wiggle through your project's setup.

Also, you avoid problems that arise from faulty preconceptions. Quite often, your first attempt will result in an awkward setup, and real elegance only arises from the lessons learned. Invest the time to learn the tool properly.

---

If you didn't know about it already, [`source_group()`](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/source_group.html) allows CMake to create a MSVC project file with the given source files grouped together, so you can have your project under CMake control but still work comfortably inside MSVC.

---

I've set up a "framework" CMake setup I am working from in various projects, perhaps you're interested in it (for inspiration or actual use): [JAWS](http://jaws.rootdirectory.de).

Comment: I always list my header files (not all included ones) as CMake sources so they show up in generated projects.

Comment: @John: You list them in appropriate `source_group()` commands, but not in `add_library()`. That is just *asking* for trouble.

Comment: `First off, it is an extremely bad idea to include header files in the list of sources.` -1, it's completely normal whether using `source_group` or not

Comment: @ruslo: Dear sir, are you intending to tell me that you would indeed state `gcc -o MyProject MyProject.c Myproject.h` on the command line? Because that is exactly what you do if you list the header files together with the sources. I couldn't care less for your downvote, but you're really out on a limb there, calling that "normal". Common, perhaps, but in error nevertheless.

Comment: command `add_executable(foo foo.cpp foo.hpp)` will not result `gcc -o foo foo.cpp foo.hpp` you can check it yourself if you don't believe me.

Comment: `but you're really out on a limb there, calling that "normal"` please show me example when it may cause some troubles? What generator? `Unix Makefiles`? `NMake Makefile`? `Xcode`? Any `Visual Studio`?

Comment: @ruslo: I will not discuss this subject with you at length here. You expressed your opinion via your downvote, I tell you to stay away from any software projects I am involved in, end of discussion. If you're really curious, post a question of your own.

Comment: Also you can look at the cmake sources: https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Source/CMakeLists.txt

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60285/discussion-between-devsolar-and-ruslo).