# cmake: trying to call msbuild during cmake script execution

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to migrate my Visual Studio solution to CMake.

I have two projects - generator (generator.exe generates C++ sources from text files) and myProj (includes some text files that have to be processed by generator.exe).
What I want is:

1. build generator project
2. use generator.exe from step1 to generate C++ source files from text files in project myProj
3. put those generated source files in resulting VS project for myProj

what I've so far:

```
###################################################################
# in root/generator/CMakeLists.txt:
set(SRC_LIST .... )
set(HDR_LIST .... )
add_executable(generator ${SRC_LIST} ${HDR_LIST})    

###################################################################
# in root/my_proj/CMakeLists.txt:

add_subdirectory(../generator/  ../generator/cmake_out)

# TRY TO BUILD GENERATOR.EXE. DON'T WORK, BECAUSE ../generator/cmake_out/ IS EMPTY YET
execute_process(COMMAND msbuild ../generator/cmake_out/generator.vcxproj)
# <copy generated files to ./src>

add_subdirectory(src)

###################################################################
# in root/my_proj/src/CMakeLists.txt:    

set(SRC_LIST SomeSource.cpp .... )
set(HDR_LIST SomeSource.h .... )

add_library(myProj STATIC ${SRC_LIST} ${HDR_LIST} )
```

So, what is wrong here? Why execute_process() fails? Seems like CMake's order of execution is absolutely chaotic.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CMake: generate sources during CMake script execution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25569106/cmake-generate-sources-during-cmake-script-execution)

Answer (score 0):

Use [ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_custom_command.html) to execute generator.exe during compilation.  Be sure to specify all of the OUTPUT files generated.  List those output files as sources for myProj.  CMake should build you a solution with two projects that will build generator first, execute it to generate the automatic myProj files, then build myProj.

```
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/output1.cpp ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/output1.h
    COMMAND generator
    DEPENDS generator
    )

add_library(myProj ${CMAKE_CURRONT_BINARY_DIR}/output.h ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/output.cpp)
```

Comment: as far as I understand - your suggestion will result in generation of source files during projects build phase (after CMake execution). That way I will not see generated files in VS projects, right?

Comment: The files will not exist until after the first build, but the names will be listed in the project file (if I remember correctly).

Comment: It is important to have these generated source files in resulting VS project. The question is - why execute_process() fails?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `execute_process` failing is the least of your problems, but to answer your question: First of all you can see the result of the called command using

```
execute_process(COMMAND msbuild ../generator/cmake_out/generator.vcxproj
                RESULT_VARIABLE result)
message(STATUS "Result: ${result}")
```

You will probably see "The system cannot find the file specified" because the CMake shell does not know what directory the msbuild command is in. You can just give the full path to msbuild, for example on my system (VS 2013), I would use:

```
execute_process(COMMAND "C:\\Program Files\\MSBuild\\14.0\\Bin\\MSBuild.exe"  
                ../generator/cmake_out/generator.vcxproj)
```